# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, react, kml

Estou tentando fazer uma requisição `HTTP` para uma `API` e recebo o seguinte `error`:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

- Porque está ocorrendo este `error`?
- Como tratar `XML` nos componentes do `React`?

**Chamada a** `API`**:**

```
  plotarCamadaNoMapa(camadas) {
        fetch('api/TelaOperadorRJ/GetXMLCamada?idCamada=' + camadas)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    xmlCamada: data

                });
            });


        console.log(this.state.xmlCamada);     
    }
```

**Arquivo** `XML`**:**

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <Style id="Style1">
      <LineStyle>
        <color>ff000000</color>
        <width>1.2</width>
      </LineStyle>
      <PolyStyle>
        <color>8000ffff</color>
        <fill>true</fill>
        <outline>true</outline>
      </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Polígono 0</name>
      <styleUrl>#Style1</styleUrl>
      <Polygon>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-46.878889999999998,-23.54439
-46.843359999999997,-23.52
-46.837859999999999,-23.516220000000001
-46.812629999999999,-23.522829999999999
-46.808340000000001,-23.54007
-46.797870000000003,-23.563590000000001
-46.814169999999997,-23.57067
-46.850740000000002,-23.56831
-46.878889999999998,-23.54439</coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
      </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: Caro Igor basta remover o `.then(response => response.json())`, XML não é JSON, logo não tem como ele interpretar isto

Comment: Ele até funcionou, mas entrou em um looping infinito.

Comment: Provavelmente é erro em outro lugar caro Igor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu acredito que o corpo de resposta do servidor não é `Content-Type:application/json`, isto não prejudica em nada em relação a manipulação dos dados recebidos, porém em minha opinião é um erro do backend não te notificar o verdadeiro tipo de conteúdo que será recebido (até mesmo por questão de segurança), pois o `Content-Type` diz para o cliente qual é o tipo de conteúdo que a resposta, de fato, tem...

Porém o seu verdadeiro problema como disse acima, você provavelmente não está recebendo um conteúdo do tipo `JSON`, com isto você está tentando forçar uma conversão que não pode, neste caso você está tentando passar um conteúdo recebido do servidor do tipo `HTML` ou `XML` para `JSON`, por isto é gerado o `error`.

**Para saber qual tipo de conteúdo você está recebendo do servidor, faça o seguinte:**

Marque a guia **"Rede"** nas ferramentas do **Chrome Dev** para ver o tipo de conteúdo da resposta do servidor, ou depure usando este código:

```
.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(response.status);
    console.log(response.json());
    console.log(response.text());
}).catch(function(err) {  
       console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);  
});
```

**Para manipular corretamente o conteúdo** `XML` **recebido, siga as instruções:**

- **1)** Remova o `response.json()`
- **2)** Para transformar o conteúdo do tipo `text` em `XML` no `React`, você pode utilizar a biblioteca [react-xml-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-xml-parser).

**Como utilizar a biblioteca** `react-xml-parser`?

Utilizando este `XML` como exemplo:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Library>
   <Books count='1'>
       <Book id='1'>
           <Name>Me Before You</Name>
           <Author>Jojo Moyes</Author>
       </Book>
   </Books>
   <Music count=1>
       <CD id='2'>
           <Name>Houses of the Holy</Name>
           <Artist>Led Zeppelin</Artist>
       </CD>
   </Music>
</Library>
```

**Passo 1):** Instale a mesma com o comando abaixo no seu terminal:

```
npm i react-xml-parser
```

**Passo 2):** Utilize o código abaixo da biblioteca para converter o conteúdo do tipo `text` para `XML` e poder manipular o mesmo.

```
var XMLParser = require('react-xml-parser');
var xml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(xmlText);
console.log(xml);
console.log(xml.getElementsByTagName('Name'));
```

**Métodos que são atualmente suportados pela biblioteca:**

> `parseFromString(string)`: Retorna um objeto `XML` conforme descrito no exemplo de saída que representa o texto de entrada.
>
> `toString(objeto XML)`: retorna a representação de texto de um `XML` de entrada.
>
> `getElementsByTagName(string)`: Retorna todas as tags com o mesmo nome da string de entrada do método (sem diferenciação de maiúsculas e minúsculas). para todas as tags possíveis, use '*' como entrada.

**Nota**

> Adicione o código do **passo (2)** dentro do seu `.then()`, substitua o `xmlText` pela sua `response` e utilize o `xml.getElementsByTagName('nomeDaTag')` de acordo com o seu cenário.

Comment: Caro Thiago, o Content-Type é indiferente, o problema é tentar forçar o conteudo em .json() quando o conteudo é um arquivo de texto em formato xml, pode colocar o content-type que quiser, o conteudo será o mesmo e não vai funcionar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu compreendo e afirmei isto também na resposta, mas em minha opnião o backend está errado em não declarar o `Content-Type` do tipo certo, pois o `Content-Type` diz para o cliente qual é o tipo de conteúdo que a resposta, de fato. Para desenvolvedores menos experientes como é o caso aqui, ele teve dificuldade por conta de talvez o `Content-Type` não estar correto (não sei se ele analisou também), por fim para eu e você que possuímos experiência, não chegaríamos ao ponto de forçar um arquivo texto em formato xml para json. Caso queira que eu aplique modificação avise.

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS por favor mostra o exemplo forçando o texto em formato de xml para json, quero ver todas as vertentes nesse processo.

Comment: @IgorCarreiro tudo bem para você?